# Intel load intrinsic issue

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd, sse2

The purpose of the code is to subtract to each character of the string str a value in the key array. The non-vectorised version of the program corresponds to the last cycle in both programs.
How is this code:

```
void decode(const char* key, int m, char* str) {
  int i; int n = strlen(str);
  __m128i k = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*) key);
  for (int i = 0; i + 16 < n; i+=m) {
    __m128i s = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) (str + i));
    s = _mm_sub_epi8(s, k);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*) (str + i), s);
  }
  for(; i<n; i++) str[i] -= key[i%m];
}
```

different from this?

```
void decode(const char* key, int m, char* str) {
  int i, n = strlen(str);
  char keybuf[16] = { 0 };
  memcpy(keybuf, key, m);
  __m128i k = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)keybuf);
  for (i=0; i+16 < n; i += m) {
    __m128i s = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(str+i));
    s = _mm_sub_epi8(s,k);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(str+i), s);
  }
  for (; i<n; i++) str[i] -= key[i % m]; }
```

Without the memory copy the same code does not work the same way.
I'm compiling with gcc -msse2.
Why is the memory copy necessary?

Comment: I think your for loop is wrong in both cases - it should be `for (int i = 0; i + 16 <= n; i += m)` - but this is probably not your main problem.

Comment: It's my professor's code I think it's right. It should be something about the string terminator...

Comment: Like I said, it's not the main problem, but you may find you do too much unnecessary work in the final scalar loop for certain values of `n` if you don't fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that in the second case you are only loading `m` characters into `keybuf`, and the remaining elements stay initialised to 0. These additional elements then have no effect on `str`.

In the first version however you most likely have non-zero elements at the end of the vector, since you blindly load all 16 elements from `key`, regardless of the actual length of the key.

To make the first version work correctly you would need to mask out the final `16 - m` elements of `k`, forcing them to be zero, e.g.

```
const int8_t mask[32] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; 
__m128i k = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*) key); // load 16 elements
k = _mm_and_si128(k, _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)&mask[16 - m]));
                                                   // mask out final 16 - m elements
```

(Note: there is probably a more efficient way of doing the masking, but it's the best I could come up with at short notice. It's still going to be more efficient than the `memcpy` version, I would guess. See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18674145/253056) for some other methods.)